# Why My website name when indexed google changes to japanese font

Tags: indexing, web, sitemap

This is a malware or what, when i type my site name keyword then changes to Japanese font? Can you tell me why its happen?[image]

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is not within the scope of questions appropriate for this site, as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) You may be able to get help on [another Stack Exchange site](http://stackexchange.com/sites#name).

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure that nobody injected malicious code in one of your website index. Maybe there is code which directs you to this site.

You can try:

1. make a new fresh clean index
2. delete all of your strange files or better templates of your website
3. try out Google Search Console